# C - set return variable as const

Tags: c, constants, return-value

I have a program that uses constant structs for parameter data (vehicle data, like transmission rates, weight etc.).

Since the program will be used for different vehicle models, I want to read the parameter data from txt-files by calling a function which feeds back the structs as return values.

Is it possible to declare the structs as 'const' in my main program? I would like to do so to guarantee that no change is made to these structs in the progress.

For further information: in the basis application of the code the parameter data is hard coded. Therefore the constant structs are used by now.

Comment: Yes it's possible. You can define them as `const` and initialize them with the return value of a function that parses the file. Upon optimizing the extra copy should be omitted.

Comment: @StoryTeller In C? Are you sure? C `const` is pretty restrictive in that it only allows constant expressions and string literals in its initializer expression, so I don't think this is going to work. In C++ yes, but not in C.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answers! 
Well if not, is there another way to guarantee that no changes are made to the structs?

Comment: Just pay attention to what data you're accessing. If you want a clean but perhaps more inefficient way, the OO way would be to never access the `struct`s directly but establish an interface to the `struct`s and only provide functions in that interface, which read from the `struct`s, never write to them except for initialization maybe.

Comment: @Downvoter - It's the only standard compliant way to initialize a constant structure short of a constant initializer. Not really a proof (but since I don't have easy access to the standard) both [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17f1721c2d2422c6) and [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb9a272c24848017) accept it.

Comment: You should bear in mind that `const` in C is just a promise that you, the programmer, are making.  Don't expect it to protect your data.

Comment: @StoryTeller OK, you're using an automatic variable here. I forgot to say I was referring to objects with *static storage duration* as said [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p4) (the website is a C11 standard draft and is very accessible, BTW). If the OP refers with "main program" to the `main` function, I agree with you. If he wants those `struct`s to have static storage duration, though, it's not going to work.

Comment: Does "main program" refer to the `main` function or just the main part of your program? Do you want to have the `struct`s in a function or outside of them?

Comment: @Downvoter - Yes, then we are on the same page. Although there are ways to get around it if the OP wants a static variable. Specifying static linkage for it with an extern pointer to a const structure and such. But I suppose the best solution really depends on the OP's setup.

Comment: Well, I am implementing the function in MATLAB Simulink as an S-Function. Using the S-Function Builder, it is not possible to declare the variable outside the function. Static duration is required. However if the 'const' statement does not protect the structs from being changed, where is the point in declaring them as 'const'?

Comment: What do you mean it isn't possible to declare the variables outside of a function, but static storage duration is required? Do you mean a `static` variable *within* a function?

Comment: Within the S-Function Builder the C-Function itself is wrapped. It is called by a gateway function, declaring the in- and outports of the block and the data types. Therefore it is only possible to declare a static variable within the function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can initialize a const with the return value of a function. But you can't assign the return value to a const.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo()
{
    return 42;
}

int main(void) {
    const int g = foo();  // OK for initializing a const
    printf("%d\n", g);
    // g = foo();;    <-- will cause compile error : assignment of read-only variable ‘g’
    return 0;
}
```